# XMLHttpRequest 'response' parameter null

Tags: javascript, audio, xmlhttprequest

The XMLHttpRequest object I have below is behaving oddly, however I am not sure if I am using it properly. To start with I needed to allow cross-domain requests on my S3 server per the instructions [located here.](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/08/amazon-s3-cross-origin-resource-sharing.html)

Next, I coded the `.open` method to go to my Amazon S3 server and perform a `GET` on the mp3 named "Superman." This seems to occur without error, however this `console.log` a couple lines down

```
console.log("Current 'request.response' value");  
console.log(request.response);
```

shows that the `request.response` is `null`. However.. in the `request.onload` function, the `request.response` object that gets passed in is shown by this `console.log` statement to be of type `AudioBuffer`.

```
    console.log("Inside 'request.onload' function");
    console.log(buffer);
```

Here is a screen shot of the console output from these two statements.

[image]

However.. when I attempt to play the mp3 in the `.onload` method, line 205 in the screen shot below throws the highlighted error.

[image]

My question is, am I using the XMLHttpRequest object and it's functions properly and if so, why am I getting this error? Do I need to run some sort of conversion on the `request.response` before or after the `.onload` method?

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/tracks/Superman.mp3', true);    
request.responseType = 'arraybuffer'; 

console.log("Current 'request.response' value");  
console.log(request.response);

request.onload = function() {
  context.decodeAudioData(request.response, function(buffer){

    console.log("Inside 'request.onload' function");
    console.log(buffer);

    var source = context.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = buffer.byteLength;
    source.connect(context.destination);
    source.start(0);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning `source.buffer = buffer.byteLength`. Try `source.buffer = buffer`.

Comment: Used a combination of this and changed the method from `.onload()` to `readyStateChanged`

Answer (score 1):

`onload` is for `window` and `Image` Objects. Maybe your code should look more like:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest;
request.open('GET', 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/tracks/Superman.mp3');    
request.responseType = 'arraybuffer'; 
console.log("Current 'request.response' value");  
console.log(request.response);
request.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200){
    context.decodeAudioData(request.response,
      function(buffer){
        console.log("Inside 'request.onload' function");
        console.log(buffer);
        var source = context.createBufferSource();
        source.buffer = buffer;
        source.connect(context.destination);
        source.start(0);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Used a combination of this new method and `source.buffer = buffer;` from the other answer. thank you!